Testing file uploads in Rails App using cucumber
I have the following cucumber test in my Rails app with the following step I attach a contract which should basically upload any file to check if upload works (upload is mandatory). Problem: I don't know how to implement this. Probably I have to generate the file on the fly and attach this.
I found 2 methods online: set (1.) & file_attach (2.) but both are not working for me:
1.
When /^I attach a contract$/ do
      page.find('#durable_contract_physical_contract').set('path/to/file.csv')
    end


file_attach(...) => file does not exist

The test code shouldn't matter but still posting this:
@javascript
Feature: Contracts

  Scenario: Creation and reading of a contract
    Given I am a non_fitaf user
      And I created a company
      And this company has a placeholder for "abc"
    When I log in successfully
      And I click on "Verträge" link
      And I click on "Neuer Vertrag" button
    Then I should see "Standard-Kunde"
      And I should see "Name"
      And I should see "Datum"
      And I should see "Von"
      And I should see "Bis"
    When I select the first customer for the contract
      And I fill in Name with "A contract"
      And I select date "29" "12" "2023" from Vertrags-Datum
      And I select date "1" "1" "2024" from Vertrags-Von
      And I select date "31" "12" "2024" from Vertrags-Bis
      And I fill in Betrag with "12,23"
      And I attach a contract
      And I submit the form
    Then I should see "Offene Services"
      And I should see "abc"


Please add the full code of how you attempted to attach files - and the error messages

I had no clue so I didnt know how to generate the file. Is now fixed! See solution below!

@dbugger was to dumb to generate the files. This doesnt happen in the app. Thought a step will automagically create the file for me for testing. This is not the case. I below posted an answer myself which works. 1. File generation 2. use spreewald gem from makandra to get the "I attach" step. You might want to upvote it. Thanks for answerinhg though!

The issue was that I wasn't able to use a file which wasn't generated.

The generation code for the file (see code below)
from the makandra spreewald gem (https://github.com/makandra/spreewald) I could use the step below

This solution solved my problem.
The code from 1.
Given /^there is a file "(.*?)"$/ do |name|
  File.open("#{name}.txt", 'w') do |f|
    f.write("some text")
  end
end

The code from 2.
I attach the file "Contract-1.txt" to "Vertragskopie"

